# How to use a scanner in a while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a method that will return the sum of the nth roots of each double x in numbers, where numbers consists of zero or more double tokens (separated by white space) and n is positive.

Examples: sumOfRoots("1.0 4.0 9.0 16.0", 2) is 10 and sumOfRoots("", 3) is 0.

```
 public static double sumOfRoots (String numbers, int n)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(numbers);
        Scanner b = scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
        int y = b.nextInt();
        double x = 0;
        while (b.hasNextDouble())
        {
            x = x + (y ^ (1 / n));
        }
        return x;
    }
```

But I keep on throwing input mismatch errors. Any idea on what I can change to make it work?

Comment: Why are you calling `nextInt()` if all your input is double?  Also, shouldn't you be reading from the scanner inside the while loop?

Comment: Also, ^ in Java is not an exponentiation operator, it's [bitwise exclusive or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: `nextInt()` handles data of `int` type, but since you are passing to scanner data like `"1.0 4.0 9.0 16.0"` its first element is `1.0` which seems to be `double`. BTW some locales use `,` to write doubles, so you may need to set proper locale to Scanner to handle it correctly like `scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);`.

Comment: Additionally, `(1 / n)` is `0` in Java (unless `n` is `1`, `-1`, or `0`); integer arithmetic doesn't return a double value.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use `Scanner`, your code can be fixed like that:

```
public static double sumOfRoots(String numbers, int n){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(numbers);
    double sum = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNextDouble())
        sum += Math.pow(scanner.nextDouble(), 1d / n);
    return sum;
}
```

In Java ^ is not an exponentional operator (as said in comments), so you have to use `Math.pow()`